# AngualrJs - change value of href in link -

Tags: angularjs, anchor, angularjs-ng-href

I can change properties in AngularJS by using a conditional If statement:

```
OrgName: org && org.id==4162 ? 'Org1' : 'Org2'
```

But i want to be able to change the `href` of a link depending on this value. How can I accomplish this? I have tried:

```
<a org && org.id==4162 ? ng-href=https://www.org1.com/ : ng-href=https://www.org2.com/>Org Link</a>
```

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ternary operator

```
<a  ng-href="{{org && org.id==4162 ? 'https://www.org1.com/':'https://www.org2.com/' }} ">Org Link</a>
```